# In this example by Bjarne, why can you pass a const qualified object to a non-const parameter?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am reading Bjarne's [Rvalue Reference Quick Look](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2027.html#Move_Semantics) and came to the following example:

```
template <class T, class A1>
std::shared_ptr<T>
factory(A1& a1)
{
    return std::shared_ptr<T>(new T(a1));
}
```

> This is much better. If a const-qualified type is passed to the
>   factory, the const will be deduced into the template parameter (A1 for
>   example) and then properly forwarded to T's constructor.

I do not understand how `::factory()` can accept a const reference. Bjarne just states that the const will be deduced into the template parameter. What exactly does this mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you pass in an lvalue of type `const X`, then `A1` will be deduced as `const X`, and you will get a function that looks like

```
std::shared_ptr<T> factory(const X& a1) { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

template type deduction normally happen in three cases:

- Parameter type is a reference or pointer, but not a universal
- reference Parameter type is a universal reference Parameter type
- is a neither reference nor pointer

your case falls into non-universal reference parameters deduction. The rules will be:
  if expression is a reference, ignore that
  pattern-match expression's type against parameter type to determine type T

For example:

```
template<typename T>
void factory(T& param);      // param is a reference

int x = 42;        // int
const int cx = x;  // copy of int
const int& rx = x; // ref to const view of int

factory(x);   // 1, T = int, param's type = int&
factory(cx);  // 2, T = const int, param's type = const int&
factory(rx);  // 3, T = const int, param's type = const int&
```

Now you can see when you pass in `const X` it matches case 2 and if you pass in `const X&` it matches case 3.

Note: std::shared_ptr is the noise in this your sample, I remove it to demonstrate type deduction.